# Module has no exported Member Vue3

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-component

I need some help with a Vue component.

I'm getting this error:

```
Failed to compile.

src/components/Btn/Btn.vue:11:14
TS2305: Module '"../../typings/button-type"' has no exported member 'ButtonType'.
     9 |     import { defineComponent, computed } from '@vue/runtime-core';
  > 11 |     import { ButtonType } from '@/typings/button-type';
       |              ^^^^^^^^^^
    12 | // components
    13 |
    14 |     export default defineComponent({
```

I'm trying to create my own type in Ts in a separate file and import it in my component.

Type:

```
export namespace ButtonType {

export type Button = {
size: Size;
type: Type;
 }
}

type Size = 'sm' | 'md' | 'lg';
type Type = 'primary' | 'accent' | 'subtle';
```

And in my component I have the following:

```
   import { ButtonType } from '@/typings/button-type';
// components

export default defineComponent({
    name: 'Btn',
    components: {},
    props: {
        size: {
            default: 'md',
        } as ButtonType.Button.size,
        type: {
            default: 'primary',
        } as ButtonType.Button.type,
    }
```

I've tried ButtonType.Button['size'] but didn't work neither.

I have some computed data etc but not relevant to the case. The main idea was to create a Type so I can identify errors when setting a wrong size or type for the button component.

Any idea of what is going on?

Answer (score 1):

Vue uses `PropType` for prop types

```js
import { defineComponent, PropType } from 'vue'
import { ButtonType } from '@/typings/button-type';

export default defineComponent({
    props: {
        size: {
            default: "md",
            type: String as PropType<ButtonType['Button']['size']>
        },
        type: {
            default: "primary",
            type: String as PropType<ButtonType['Button']['type']>
        }
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: I've tried but I got the following error:

TS2352: Conversion of type 'string' to type 'PropType ' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.

Comment: @PaulB Sorry, I made some errors, try the updated answer.

Comment: I had to change the ButtonType because it is a namespace so I can't use it with PropType<>. Now I export only ButtonType as a type and I reference it as you did but got another error 

`Module '"../../typings/button-type"' has no exported member 'Button'.`

 I'm not sure what is going on

Comment: I've try some stuff. Aparently if I only use the Size and Type as types, it works
`export type Size = 'sm' | 'md' | 'lg' ` 
but exporting the button it won't